# Spring Boot - Save User between Controller Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What's the best approach to avoid repeating the same userService DB lookup over and over again in my controller methods?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.2 with `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` for templating.

I tried adding an instance variable for `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` but it gave me a NullPointerException.

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Value("${product.name}")
    private String productName;


    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

      modelAndView.addObject("email", user.getEmail());

      modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");

      return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard/faq", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView faq(){
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

      modelAndView.addObject("email", user.getEmail());
      modelAndView.addObject("productname", productName);

      modelAndView.setViewName("faq");

      return modelAndView;
   }
```

Comment: If you're doing the same thing repeatedly, either A) create a controller superclass, B) Create a servlet filter, or C) Create a Spring interceptor. In this case, I'd do option C.

Comment: I'd rather use option D) provide custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

Comment: Or... Spring Security, and leave these kind of checks out of your controllers

Comment: But topic starter probably have asked about session and session attributes.

Comment: I think @A_B is not talking about code repetition, but storing something somewhere in order to make less round trips to the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get at the user that is stored in the session, you can use this annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/me")
public User me(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    return user;
}
```

If you then want the user to always be available in thymeleaf I would use a `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class GlobalVariablesControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User user() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        User user = null;
        // get user from authentication, but make sure to check for nulls

        return user;
    }

}
```